# Java mail api, unseen messeges not working as i expcted

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail

```
private Message[] getNewMssgs() {
    Message message[];
    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(new Properties(), null);
        store = session.getStore("pop3s");
        store.connect(host, username, password);
        inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
        FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, false);
        message = inbox.search(unseenFlagTerm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        informError(e);
        return null;
    }
    if (message!=null)
            if (message.length>0) 
                return message; 
    return null;
}
```

this is the method i use for reading mails from gmail, it works great most of the time, but sometimes it returns null even though i see new messeges on my gmail account on a browser (which means it thinks there are no new mssgs when there are)... anyone familiar with that?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation for the [com.sun.mail.pop3 package](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html), the POP3 protocol doesn't support any flags.  Use the [IMAP protocol](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail) instead.